# Flutter version conflict with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Error Details :

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.    > Could not find com.android.tools.build.gradle:7.2.2:.      Required by:          project :    > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0:.      Required by:          project : "  This And i'm using "Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1" as my studio version  " app\build.gradle : "  " minSdkVersion 32 "  dependencies {     implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0') }  and my "android\build.gradle :" is dependencies {         classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:7.2.2'         classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0'         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"     } ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

How should i resolve this? I tried by changing the gradle and gms-google versions as by release notes,also i had been trying to change minSdk versions for "19" , "21" and "32" aswell, but i couldn't identified it to resolve this.